# Query Radio Button Clicked event with JavaScript and IE8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, webforms

I'm working with a Webforms page to which I added a simple YES/NO radio button.  I created a JavaScript function that queries the radio button and it works fine with Chrome but fails with IE8 (the corporate standard browser).  I'm flummoxed trying to come up with a way to see which button was clicked when running with IE8.  This is the button from the HTML page:

```
<td width="35%">
    <label class="label_bold floatLeft" style="margin-top: .25em">Clinicals sent:</label>
 </td>
<td width="15%">       
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtClinicalsSent" 
                         AutoPostBack="true" 
                         RepeatLayout="Flow" 
                         RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                         OnClick="rbtClinicalsSent_clicked()"
                         OnTextChanged="rbtClinicalsSent_TextChanged" 
                         runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Yes</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="0">No</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</td>
```

My JavaScript function (copied from somewhere else on StackOverflow) works fine with Chrome (haven't tried Firefox).

```
function rbtClinicalsSent_clicked() {
    /* This is based on the assumption that the first element
       in the radio button is Yes */
    var yesButtonClicked = false;
    var radioButton;
    radioButton = document.getElementsByName("rbtClinicalsSent");
    for (i= 0; i< radioButton.length; i++){ 
        if (radioButton[i].checked & rbtIdx===0) 
            yesButtonClicked = true;
    };
    return yesButtonClicked;
};
```

When I run the debugger with IE8 and look at the methods available for the "rbtClinicalsSent" radio button it appears as though there is nothing available to premit checking the "clicked" status.  An ideal solution, I presume, would be to dump IE8, which isn't possible in this corporate environment.

TIA
Scott

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  In IE8 *radioButton[0]* contains some meta data but not a checked property.  The possibly somewhat useful property is innerText, which for two radio buttons saying "Yes" and "No" the innerText is "YesNo".  The fix was to check "typeof(RadioButton[i])==="undefined".  Below is the same function that works for IE8, Chrome, and Firefox.

```
function rbtClinicalsSentYes_clicked() {
/* This is based on the assumption that the first element
   in the radio button is Yes */
var yesButtonClicked = false;
var radioButton;
radioButton = document.getElementsByName("rbtClinicalsSent");
for (i= 0; i< radioButton.length; i++){ 
    if (typeof(radioButton[i].checked) === "undefined") {
        continue;
    }
    if (radioButton[i].checked & rbtIdx===0) 
        yesButtonClicked = true;
};
return yesButtonClicked;
```

};